# modeling advice for table which may have 2 father tables

Tags: database-design, erd

I am developing a ERP for a small cooperative with special needs (that'y why they need a non-general solution).

I'd like to model the following:
A "receipt" can either be incoming or outgoing
For that I'd like to have three tables: 
collection | payment | receipt
So a receipt can belong to a Collection or a Payment

I'd like to model the Receipt table
with id, collection_id (fk), payment_id (fk)
so there would be a 0,1:n relation from both father tables to the receipt table.

Does that make sense from a DB development view?
Or is there another recommended way to model multiple inheritance?

The same question applies to a a document (image, PDF, etc.) - any uploadable resource:
A document can either belong to an activity, a receipt, a project, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would Simply add a `receipt_id` to the `collection` and `payment` table.

This is a better design (objectively normalised) that allows your model to grow should your requirements change

This would solve the problem for your `document` model also - activity, reciept, project would contain a `document_id`, and you could expand your model to include any number of tables containing a `document_id`.

If you need to differentiate between documents stored in the table itself, you could add a `document_type` to make that distinction.

Comment: got it... problem is that this would allow only 1:1 relationships but I understand the general idea. In my usecase a payment could be for several receipts (for example you bought 3 things for a project, in 3 different stores, but the company pays you the total amount back).
I guess it's better to normalize collection and payment in one table "account movement" which then can be associated to several receipt_id's